# Setting up email account on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, email-server, accounts

I am very new in server management thing. I want to make email accounts like info@mysite.com.
I know something to do with Sendmail thing , but dunno what ?

I am on Ubuntu 10 server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ubuntu Server Guide contains a complete chapter on [Email Services](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/email-services.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are some good walkthroughs on setting this kind of thing up at How To Forge.  I wouldn't follow any of them exactly since they won't perfectly match your requirements, but [this one](http://www.howtoforge.com/virtual-users-domains-postfix-courier-mysql-squirrelmail-ubuntu-10.04) seems pretty much what you are looking for.

Personally I'd go for Dovecot over Courier, though only because it's what I'm used to.  So maybe [this one](http://www.howtoforge.com/postfix-virtual-hosting-with-ldap-backend-and-with-dovecot-as-imap-pop3-server-on-ubuntu-karmic-koala-9.10), though that's using an LDAP backend and is for 9.10.

Anyway, those two should at least give you an idea of the steps involved - even if they're not exactly what you are wanting to do.